# Не работает ReadConsole

Tags: windows, winapi, ассемблер, fasm

Недавно решил освоить fasm для windows x32 (До этого писал под MSDOS). Пытаюсь разобраться с функцией ReadConsoleA из WinAPI. Ввод запрашивает, а вот в буфер ничего не записывает.

```
format PE console

entry start

include 'win32ax.inc'


section '.text' code readable executable

start:  invoke  AllocConsole
        invoke  GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
        mov     [stdout], eax
        invoke  GetStdHandle, STD_INPUT_HANDLE
        mov     [stdin], eax

        invoke  ReadConsole, [stdin], input, 8, 0, 0
        invoke  WriteConsole, [stdout], input, in_len, 0, 0

        invoke  SleepProcess, 2000
        invoke  ExitProcess, 0


section '.data' data readable writable

stdout  dd      ?
stdin   dd      ?

input   db      8 dup (?), 0
in_len  dd      ?


section '.idata' import data readable writable

library kernel32, 'kernel32.dll'

import  kernel32, \
        AllocConsole, 'AllocConsole', \
        GetStdHandle, 'GetStdHandle', \
        SleepProcess, 'Sleep', \
        ExitProcess, 'ExitProcess', \
        WriteConsole, 'WriteConsoleA', \
        ReadConsole, 'ReadConsoleA'
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы передаёте функции некорректные аргументы:

```
invoke  ReadConsole, [stdin], input, 8, 0, 0
                                        ^
```

Дело в том, что [согласно MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsole) предпоследний параметр (`lpNumberOfCharsRead`) помечен как *[out]*. Соответственно, функция согласно контракту ожидает в нём ненулевой указатель (иначе он был бы помечен как *[out, optional]* — такое у MSDN соглашение).

Для исправления ошибки вам необходимо выделить на стеке область и передавать указатель на неё, даже если значение в ней вам не потребуется. Почему именно на стеке? Только для того, чтобы не плодить лишние элементы в [таблице релоков (relocations)](https://wasm.in/threads/chto-takoe-reloki.19598/))*

Пример :

```
; Вместо отмотки вершины можно использовать уже ненужную локальную переменную
add esp, -4
; TODO: удостовериться, что параметры кладутся макросом через `mov [esp + N], foo`, а не
; через `push foo`, иначе переданный нами указатель на вершину будет разрушен, что
; потребует его предварительного сохранения в отдельный регистр
invoke  ReadConsole, [stdin], input, 8, esp, 0
add esp, 4
```

К слову, с последующим вызовом `WriteConsole()` та же история.

Comment: Если попробовать скомпилировать исходник из вопроса с помощью fasm, то полученном исполняемом файле не будет таблицы релокаций, не смотря на наличие глобальных переменных. У exe-файла она может быть, а может и отсутствовать. У динамической библиотеки при наличии глобальных переменных она гарантированно будет. Ну и в целом, если заморачиваться по поводу глобальных переменных - то из соображения архитектуры, а не наличия/отсутствия таблицы релокаций.

Comment: Пытался класть и в стек и в переменную. Никаких ошибок, но введенная строка по прежнему не выводится.

Comment: @RedalErm 1) Что возвращает `ReadConsole()`? 2) Что возвращает `GetLastError()`, если его вызвать сразу же после `ReadConsole()`?

Answer (score 0):

Правильный вариант такой:

```
invoke  ReadConsole,  [stdin], input, 8, in_len, 0
invoke  WriteConsole, [stdout], input, [in_len], 0, 0 ; in_len должен передаваться по значению
```

1. В функцию [**`ReadConsole`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsole) 4-м параметром нужно передавать адрес переменной (указатель на переменную), куда будет записано количество фактически прочитанных символов. Если передать 0, то программа упадет при обращении по нулевому указателю (это видно при запуске программы под отладчиком). Это то что вам уже подсказали в соседнем ответе.
2. В [**`WriteConsole`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsole) 3-м параметром нужно передать это количество по значению (как число, а не как адрес переменной, где это число лежит), поэтому нужны квадратные скобки вокруг `in_len`. Когда в качестве количества выводимых символов передается не маленькое число, а адрес (что-то типа `402011h`, что равно `4202513` в десятичной системе), то функция понимает, что что-то не так, и ничего в итоге не выводит. 4-й параметр этой функции (количество выведенных байт) по факту не обязателен, хотя в документации не обозначен, как optional.

Вообще в таких случаях очень помогает использование отладчика - к примеру, после исправления первого пункта в отладчике видно, что строка в память считалась, хотя ничего и не вывелось.

[image: Скриншот]

Также полезно читать документацию по используемым функциям. Например [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsole) написано следующее:

> ## Return value
>
> If the function **succeeds**, the return value is **nonzero**.
>
> If the function **fails**, the return value is **zero**. To get extended error
>   information, call `GetLastError`.

На скриншоте выше как раз видно, что после вызова функции в `EAX` лежит ноль (функция кладет возвращаемое значение в eax по [соглашению о вызове stdcall](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5#%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85,_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0_x86_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_32-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)), значит уже что-то не так. А в `LastErr` (последняя ошибка) написана конкретная проблема: `ERROR_NOACCESS` - no access, нет доступа.